# XPath concat function: \n appears as text

Tags: string, xpath, concatenation, xslt-1.0, xpath-1.0

I 'm wring Xpath scripts using concat function to display the result in lines using XPath 1.0

XML example

```
<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

XPath

```
concat("To : ", /note/to , ' \n  ', "From : ", /note/from, ' \n  ', "Heading : ", /note/heading, ' \n  ', "Body : ", /note/body)
```

Result

```
To : Tove \n  From : Jani \n  Heading : Reminder \n  Body : Don't forget me this weekend!
```

However when I use the concat with two element and "\n" in between it works fine.

xPath:

```
concat("To : ", /note/to , ' \n  ', "From : ", /note/from)
```

Result:

```
To : Tove 
From : Jani
```

Comment: Use &#10; in stead of \n

Comment: unfortunately, it doesn't resolve the issue

Comment: Show us your XSLT code. Just adding a tag is not enough.

Comment: I'm using Infor M3 ERP system so we are getting the path, then the string result is converted from "String to QR code"

Comment: I have no idea what Infor M3 ERP system is. Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

XPath doesn't recognise backslash as an escape character. `"\n"` simply represents the two characters "backslash, 'n'", it doesn't represent a newline.

If your XPath expression is embedded in a host language such as Java or C#, then the host language will convert `\n` to newline before the XPath engine ever sees it. But you don't say anything about the host language in which the expressions appear.

If your XPath expression appears within XSLT or XQuery, then you should write a newline as `&#xa;` or `&#x10;`. If it's some other environment, then you can use a literal newline.

So the answer is, it all depends on the host environment in which you are writing these expressions.

Comment: The characters appear in the string as txt. the problem not resolved yet. Hopefully there is another way.

Comment: Well, you could make a start by answering the question: how are you running this XPath expression?